# Is there a mathematical Definition for Centroids

Tags: geometry, analysis

I was curious about whether there is a mathematical definition for Centroids or not . In reality it is pretty obvious but I think that values of Centroids would also play a role in statistics in term of finding optimum solutions . I was also curious if centroids were discovered by physicists first then made mathematical or the opposite . In  College I have seen a lot of really easy mathematical concepts made hard just because of using  symbols and sets instead of easy visual representations . I wonder if that is the case too with centroids 
Thanks!!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#By_integral_formula This gives us a proper definition of a centroid for every figure you'd encounter in real life.

Comment: I think the issue is larger than that: it deals with **means** (and there are a lot of them : arithmetic, geometric, harmonic, logarithmic... and many more). A mean is $n$ dimensions can be computed by means for each component, for example the geometrical mean of $\{ (2,3), (2,12) \}$ would be $(2,16)$...